# Why won't my wordpress widget settings save?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm making a pretty basic widget, and I've made many in the past with no issue but for some reason certain areas of my settings won't save. Namely the settings for "`$postTypeSelect`", "`$postTypeNumber`", "`$selectedPostTag`". The are the only items that are "generated" at runtime, they may be the issue, not sure.

```
<?php
    add_action('widgets_init','register_postTypeWidget');

    function register_postTypeWidget(){
        register_widget('postType_widget_start');
    }

    class postType_widget_start extends WP_Widget {
        function postType_widget_start() {  
            $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'postTypeWidget', 'description' => __('Display Posts by Post Type') );  
            $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'posttype-widget' );  
            $this->WP_Widget( 'posttype-widget', __('Posts by Post Type', 'postType_widget'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );  
        }
         function widget($args, $instance) {
            extract($args); 

            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            $postTypeSelect = $instance['postTypeSelect'];
            $postTypeNumber = $instance['postTypeNumber'];
            $selectedPostTag = $instance['selectedPostTag'];
            $showDate = $instance['showDate'];
            $showAuthor = $instance['showAuthor'];

            $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => $postTypeNumber,
            'orderby'          => 'post_date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            'post_type'        => $postTypeSelect );

            $postList = get_posts($args);

            echo $before_widget;
            ?>
<!-- 
                <p class="widget-title">News &amp; Announcements</p>
                <ul class="posts-by-tag-list">
                    <li class="posts-by-tag-item news" id="posts-by-tag-item-33">
                        <a class="posts-by-tag-item-title" href="http://dev.douglascountysoccer.com/intrinsicly-evolve-excellent-alignments/">Intrinsicly evolve excellent alignments</a> <small>Posted on: September 14, 2013</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
 -->
            <?php
            echo $after_widget;

        }
        function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {  

            $instance = $old_instance;

            $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
            $instance['postTypeSelect'] = $new_instance['postTypeSelect'] ;
            $instance['postTypeNumber'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['postTypeNumber'] );
            $instance['selectedPostTag'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['selectedPostTag'] );
            $instance['showDate'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['showDate'] );
            $instance['showAuthor'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['showAuthor'] );

            return $instance;

        }
        function form( $instance ) {    
        $defaults = array( 'title' => __(''), 'postTypeSelect' => __(''), 'postTypeNumber' =>  __(''), 'selectedPostTag' =>  __(''), 'showDate' =>  __(''), 'showAuthor' =>  __('') );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);   

        $args = '';
        $output = 'object';
        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output );
        $posttags = get_tags();
    ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title'); ?></label>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeSelect' ); ?>"><?php _e('Select Post Type'); ?></label>
                <?php 
                    echo '<select name="postTypeSelect" style="width:100%;">';
                    echo '<option value="">Select Post Type</option>';
                    foreach($post_types as $post_type) {
                        if($instance['postTypeSelect'] == $post_type->name)
                            echo '<option value="'.$post_type->name.'" selected >'.$post_type->label.'</option>';
                        else 
                            echo '<option value="'.$post_type->name.'" >'.$post_type->label.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeNumber' ); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Posts'); ?></label>
                <?php 
                    echo '<select name="postTypeNumber" style="width:100%;">';
                    else
                        echo '<option value="0">test</option>';
                    for($x=1; $x < 11; $x++) {
                        if($instance['postTypeNumber'] == $x)
                            echo '<option value="'.$x.'" selected >'.$x.'</option>';
                        else
                            echo '<option value="'.$x.'" >'.$x.'</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'selectedPostTag' ); ?>" style="display:block;width:100%;"><?php _e('Show Only Posts with These Tags (optional)'); ?></label>
                <?php
                    foreach($posttags as $postTag){
                        if($instance['selectedPostTag'] == $postTag->term_id)
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedPostTag[]" value="'.$postTag->term_id.'" checked />'.$postTag->name.'</br>';
                        else
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedPostTag[]" value="'.$postTag->term_id.'" />'.$postTag->name.'</br>';
                    }
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'additional_options' ); ?>" style="display:block;width:100%;"><?php _e('Additional Options'); ?></label>
                <?php if($instance['showDate'] == 'showDate'): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showDate' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showDate' ); ?>" value="showDate" checked />Show Date</br>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showDate' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showDate' ); ?>" value="showDate" />Show Date</br>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($instance['showAuthor'] == 'showAuthor'): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" value="showAuthor" checked />Show Author</br>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" value="showAuthor" />Show Author</br>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
    <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form elements don't have the correct `name` attribute (and `id`):
You should use:

```
 <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postTypeSelect' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeSelect' ); ?>"> .... </select>

<select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postTypeNumber' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeNumber' ); ?>"> ...   </select>

<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'selectedPostTag' ); ?>[]" />
```

**UPDATE:**
Also I found that `$instance['selectedPostTag']` was not updating correctly, as it may hold multiple values.
Here's the `update` and `form` functions for your widget:

```
 function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {  

    $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['postTypeSelect'] = $new_instance['postTypeSelect'] ;
        $instance['postTypeNumber'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['postTypeNumber'] );
        $instance['selectedPostTag'] = $new_instance['selectedPostTag'];
        $instance['showDate'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['showDate'] );
        $instance['showAuthor'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['showAuthor'] );

        return $instance;

    }

function form( $instance ) {    

    $defaults = array( 
        'title' => __(''), 
        'postTypeSelect' => __(''), 
        'postTypeNumber' =>  __(''), 
        'selectedPostTag' =>  __(''), 
        'showDate' =>  __(''), 
        'showAuthor' =>  __('') 
    );

    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);   

    $args = '';
    $output = 'object';
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output );
    $posttags = get_tags();
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeSelect' ); ?>"><?php _e('Select Post Type'); ?></label>
        <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postTypeSelect' ); ?>"> 
        <?php        
                echo '<option value="">Select Post Type</option>';
                foreach($post_types as $post_type) {
                    if($instance['postTypeSelect'] == $post_type->name)
                        echo '<option value="'.$post_type->name.'" selected >'.$post_type->label.'</option>';
                    else 
                        echo '<option value="'.$post_type->name.'" >'.$post_type->label.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'postTypeNumber' ); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Posts'); ?></label>
        <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'postTypeNumber' ); ?>"> 
        <?php                          
            echo '<option value="0">test</option>';
            for($x=1; $x < 11; $x++) {
                if($instance['postTypeNumber'] == $x)
                    echo '<option value="'.$x.'" selected >'.$x.'</option>';
                else
                    echo '<option value="'.$x.'" >'.$x.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'selectedPostTag' ); ?>" style="display:block;width:100%;"><?php _e('Show Only Posts with These Tags (optional)'); ?></label>

            <?php

                foreach($posttags as $postTag){
                ?>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'selectedPostTag' ) ?>[]" value="<?php echo $postTag->term_id ?>" <?php foreach ( $selected_tags as $checked ) { checked( $checked, $postTag->term_id, true ); }?> />
                  <?php echo $postTag->name ?>
                  </br>
                <?php     
                }
            ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'additional_options' ); ?>" style="display:block;width:100%;"><?php _e('Additional Options'); ?></label>
            <?php if($instance['showDate'] == 'showDate'): ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showDate' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showDate' ); ?>" value="showDate" checked />Show Date</br>
            <?php else: ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showDate' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showDate' ); ?>" value="showDate" />Show Date</br>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if($instance['showAuthor'] == 'showAuthor'): ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" value="showAuthor" checked />Show Author</br>
            <?php else: ?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'showAuthor' ); ?>" value="showAuthor" />Show Author</br>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
<?php
    }
```